# Xbox 360 not connecting to Xbox One via HDMI

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, hdmi

I have read a few places online stating that Xbox 360 can be plugged into the HDMI cable in port on an Xbox One and 360 games can be played via the tv snap in by accessing the 360. Sounds simple enough but I am getting a no signal from cable error when I try this. Can anyone shed light here? I did test the 360 by plugging it directly into the TV to make sure the HDMI cable works properly with my 360 and it plays fine. Any other set-up steps need to take place?

Comment: It works fine when you connect the 360 to the TV, but you get a "no signal" when you connect the 360 to the One? Are you sure *both* consoles are turned on? That's important; even if you only want to play 360, the One must be turned on as well.

Comment: Hmm, the only other reasons I can think of would return a "*signal out of range*" error, and not a "*no signal*". Sorry for not being more helpful than that.

Comment: I've had problems using a lower quality HDMI cable when I used my Xbox One as a pass through for my cable box.  Switching the cable to a higher quality HDMI solved it for me.  Perhaps you're in the same boat?

Answer (score 2):

If your Xbox 360 is not playing though the Xbox One, this is what you should do, to find and, hopefully remove, the problem.

**Test the Xbox 360**

Plug the HDMI into your television and see if it works. Try the same cable, first, and the cable used on your Xbox One if it still doesn't work.

If the Xbox works without swapping the cables, everything on the 360 side is O.K.

If you have to change cables, your issue is with the HDMI cable. Try the new cable in your Xbox One.

**Test the HDMI in on your Xbox One**

Try connecting a different device to your Xbox One. A blu-ray player, your computer, even a set top box is fine (as long as you have HDMI out).

If other devices don't work, you may have a faulty HDMI in port.

**If these tests are inconclusive**

If the fault has not been found, you may simply need a better quality cable.

Quality does not make as much of a difference with HDMI as it did with component. You are always going to get next to perfect quality - if it works.

Some devices need a bit more power in the cable. Try a cable rated for 4K. Look for gold tips if you want to be sure. ***"Braided cable" does not improve quality***. It just makes the cable less likely to break under strain.

I hope you find your solution here. I can personally vouch for cheap cable, here. The cable I am using cost me ten bucks, and it cost the store $2.